# How are Tezos operations encoded?

Tags: transactions, serialization, parse

Given a transaction in its serialized format, how do you parse it to get the destination, the amount, and the other fields?

I am not asking for library or RPC endpoint to achieve this but for an explanation of how each field is encoded in the serialized raw hex.

Here is an example of a raw hex:

```
008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46c008cb5baedee4dc3ec261dfcf57a9600bb0a8e26c0f00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d009595facf847a72b4c3fe231c0e4185e68e9b2875aa3c639382c86bcf0af23699f47fe66a6550ade936a5b59d5919ad20703885750314e0c368b277de39e7d10a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of an encoded operation group is the following:

```
<branch : 32 bytes>
<tag#0 : nat> | <content#0>
... 
<tag#n : nat> | <content#n>
<signature (optional) : 64 bytes>
```

Extracting branch:

1. Append `0x0134` prefix
2. *Base58* encode with checksum

Extracting signature:

1. Append `0x04822b` prefix
2. *Base58* encode with checksum

Operation tag by kind (as of Carthage):

- `0` for *endorsement*
- `5` for *proposal*
- `6` for *ballot*
- `1` for *seed_nonce_revelation*
- `2` for *double_endorsement_evidence*
- `3` for *double_baking_evidence*
- `4` for *activate_account*
- `107` for *reveal*
- `108` for *transaction*
- `109` for *origination*
- `110` for *delegation*

Content encoding depends on the operation kind, in your question you were likely referring to "transaction", so let's take it as an example:

```
<source : key_hash>
<fee : nat>
<counter : nat>
<gas_limit : nat>
<storage_limit : nat>
<amount : nat>
<destination : address>
<has_parameters? : bool>
<parameters (optional)>
```

"has_parameters" flag is `False` if at least one of the conditions is met:

- Transaction content does not contain "parameters" field
- "parameters" field has value `{"entrypoint": "default", "value": {"prim": "Unit"}}`

Parameters are encoded as follows:

```
<entrypoint tag : 1 byte> | <entrypoint name (optional)>
<encoded value length : 4 bytes, big endian> | <value : micheline>
```

Entrypoint tag depends on the entrypoint name (can be reserved):

- `0x00` for *default*
- `0x01` for *root*
- `0x02` for *do*
- `0x03` for *set_delegate*
- `0x04` for *remove_delegate*
- `0xff` otherwise

Entrypoint name is encoded as `<encoded name length : 1 byte> | <utf-8 encoded name>`

Out of scope of this answer:

- Forging primitives: `nat`, `key_hash`, `address`, `bool`
- Forging Micheline values

---

Breakdown for the sample opg hex:

```
branch 
008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d4
BKiXcfN1ZTXnNNbTWSRArSWzVFc6om7radWq5mTqGX6rY4P2Uhe

tag
6c
transaction

source
008cb5baedee4dc3ec261dfcf57a9600bb0a8e26c0
tz1YU2zoyCkXPKEA4jknSpCpMs7yUndVNe3S

fee
f00b
1520

counter
dd85a001
2622173

gas_limit
8452
10500

storage_limit
ac02
300

amount
e0a712
300000

destination
000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d
tz2FwBnXhuXvPAUcr1aF3uX84Z6JELxrdYxD

has_parameters
00
false

signature
9595facf847a72b4c3fe231c0e4185e68e9b2875aa3c639382c86bcf0af23699f47fe66a6550ade936a5b59d5919ad20703885750314e0c368b277de39e7d10a
sighZMqWz5G8drK1VTsmTnQBFEQ9kxQQxL88NFh8UaqDEJ3R3mzgR3g81azadZ9saPwsWga3kEPsyfbzrXm6ueuDvx3pQ5Q9
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I believe the raw hex from my question is a "transaction" operation. Can you decode that in your answer to show what values the different fields have for this example?

Comment: Thanks for the decoding of the example. Bounty awarded.